# java -jar and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, makefile, raspberry-pi

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/java/src/driver# make run
java -jar Core.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pi4j/io/gpio/GpioFactory
```

I used and altered a makefile that I'm sure of is correct, but let me include it as well:
http://pastebin.com/nzenp2E8

What do I do wrong?

Edit: 
I know the imports are correct
And I've already tried like giving `java -jar Core.jar` a classpath in several ways, but the same error keeps popping up.

Comment: Did you misspell something? Shouldn't it be `com.pi4j.io` instead of `come.pi4j.io`?

Comment: You need a manifest.mf in the META-INF folder of your executable JAR.  That's how you specify CLASSPATH.

Comment: duffymo is right - the `-cp` or `-classpath` options do not work in combination with `-jar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create jar with -e option [specify application entry point for stand-alone application bundled into an executable jar file]:

```
jar cfe Core.jar pract2.Solution pract2\*
```

Here pract2.Solution is main class.

Run using
java -jar Core.jar
Or
java -cp .;Core.jar -jar Core.jar